# Angular mat-select not displaying object property on edit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I am using angular mat-select to display a list from WebAPI. It display correct what i need from "zone" table (Zoneid, Zname). On submit I save the Zoneid (which is foreign key on operation table).

1- Populate mat-select with all the zones: Work (on create or on edit Mode)
2- On edit: when I select an "operation" (from operations table) row from mat-table list to edit, the form load the object and set controls (inputs text) with all the values.. except mat-select component it is not set with value that i have saved..when I open mat-select it display all the zones list (like I said before) it seems that mat-select does not map Zone id with its name values !!!

This is my code.

## HTML

```
 <mat-form-field>
     <mat-select formControlName="ZoneID"  placeholder="XXXX">
          <mat-option>None</mat-option>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let zone of zoneList | async">
          <mat-option value="{{zone.ZID}}">{{zone.Zone}}</mat-option>
          </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

## Component and service get method

```
zoneList: Observable<Array<Zone>>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    
this.zoneList = this.zoneService.getZoneList();
```

## Ts Service

```
getZoneList():Observable<Zone[]>  {
   
 return this.http.get<Zone[]>(environment.apiURL+'/Zones');  
  }
```

## WebAPI

```
  //GET: api/Zones
 public List<ZonesInfo> GetZones() 
    {    
     var res = from a in db.Zones
               select new ZonesInfo() { ZID = a.ZoneID, Zone = a.Zname };
            return res.ToList();
    }
```

## Zone Model

```
export class Zone {
    
    ZID: number;
    Zone: string;
   
}
```

Whats wrong with my code !!! ?

Comment: In order to have access and in this case, to display zone name in your table you need to save the object (in the database for example) with both properties.
Otherwise how the application will now that your object has a name property and which to display it?!

Comment: base on your answer if I have two tables one called invoice and other called customer, I have to save all customer details in Invoice table !!! best practice said I need just to save customerId as foreign key in Invoice table...

Comment: I don't know the structure of your database, but yes, you should save only the customerId as foreign key in the invoice collection or table and based on that key you can retrieve the customer details.

Comment: the structure of my database as I said before is very simple i have tow tables one called "Operations" like "Invoice" and another table called "Zone" like "Customer"... i m using mat-table to display my Operations list == when i select one of my operation to edit...i want to  load the zone name to mat-select while i m saving just the zoneid on my operations table

Answer (score 0):

html select and a mat-select  have a list of option items. Each option has a value (this is for storing in model or database) and a label:

```
<mat-select>
   <mat-option 
       *ngFor="let z of zones" [value]="z.id">{{z.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

What you need to do this is a mapping of all Zone ids and zone names. These static data can be hardcoded in your app or can be loaded from backend.

static in the same component:

```
readonly zones = [
    { id: 'z1': name: 'label1' },
    { id: 'z2': name: 'label2' },
    { id: 'z3': name: 'label3' },
    ...
];
```

backend, loaded in component:

```
loadZones() { 
    return this.http.get('assets/data/zones.json');
}

ngOnInit() {
    loadZones()
    .subscribe(arr => {
         this.zones = arr;
    });
```

In this case: don't forget to [unsubscribe](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f)

Comment: my question is on edit how can i load Zname1 if i only store Zoneid1

Comment: This part work for me as I said before..but my problem is that I want to save just Zoneid in my "Operation" table as a foreign key...but on edit how can I get zone name for the Zoneid that I saved in Operation table (this like invoice table and Customer table..in Invoice table we need just to save customerid as a foreign key)